# Practice with closed sequences

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Okay I have a final coming up, but I realized that I am still not adept at writing proofs.

*Prove that if $\lim_{n\to \infty}p_n = p$  in a given metric space then the set of points {$p, p_1, p_2, p_3, ... $} is closed.

Proof:

For any $\epsilon$ > 0. There is an index $N > 0$ such that $d(p_n, p) < \epsilon$ for any $n > N$. Let there be a point ${q,q_n} \notin ${$p_n$} such that we can form an open interval ($q, q_n$) where {$p_n$} $\subset ($$q$, $q_n$).

Now let the $d(q, p) < \epsilon$, similarly, $d(q_n, p_n) < \epsilon$. However, we can make a smaller interval say ${q_0, q_{0n}} \notin {p_n}$ such that we can form another smaller interval ($q_0, q_{0n}$) where {$p_n$} $\subset ($$q_0$, $q_{0n}$).

with $d(q_0, p) < \epsilon$/2, similarly, $d(q_{0n}, p_n) < \epsilon$/2. We can do this infinitely many times such that the smallest interval that contains {$p_n$} exclusively is the closed interval [$p, p_1, p_2, ...$].

PROOF IS COMPLETE

Comment: I cannot edit your post because the change is less than six characters. You can write $\infty$ by using \infty

Comment: What's an open interval? Aren't you in an arbitrary metric space?

Comment: A set is closed if it contains all its limit points. Show that p is the only limit point of $p_n$ that's not in the set. Also, there cannot exist p' as a limit point that's not in the set. If p' existed, then it would be the limit of a subsequence. However, all subsequences must converge to p.

Answer (score 0):

I am not so sure about what you mean by "interval." Interval is only defined on $\mathbb{R}$. In general metric space, I think it will be a good idea to work with balls, sets of the form $\{y;d(x,y)<r\}$, an open ball centered at $y$ with radius $r$. For this specific problem, try to show the complement $\{q_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}^c$ is open.

Comment: So, through using triangle inequality properties i would have to show that it is impossible for some q to be in {$p_n$}.

Comment: You can start with a point $q$ in the complement and try to show that there exists a small open ball around $q$ that also lies in the complement. Then check the definition of open set and use the argument that complement of open set is closed.